# Archive some entities with inheritance

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a hard problem to solve and I don't know how to do it.

I want to archive some entities and then delete them from initial tables. Problem is these entities are linked together. I have a code which is close to working but I think it's not a clean way to do it. It's composed of SQL queries which copy rows with their IDs to new tables. 
Another problem is that I don't need some fields to archive so archive entities are not exactly the same as initial entities.
I'm using raw SQL query and not DQL because of the size of my tables.

I want to archive these entities : Colle, ColleQC, QC, PasserColle, Reponse, ReponseQC, StatistiqueColle, StatistiqueQuestion, RepartitionColle, RepartitionQuestion, Tuteur
TO
BanqueColle, BanqueColleQC, BanqueQC, BanquePasserColle, BanqueReponse, BanqueReponseQC, BanqueStatistiqueColle, BanqueStatistiqueQuestion, BanqueRepartitionColle, BanqueRepartitionQuestion, AncienAdherent.

I'll use these archive for another part of my app.

**Sample of table structure :**[image]

(Tuteur and AncienAdherent extend User)

Here's a part of the code I made to archive but I don't think it's a clean way to do it :

```
public function archiveTuteurs() {
    $db = $this->em->getConnection();
    $query = "INSERT INTO ancien_adherent (id)
              SELECT u.id
              FROM user u
              WHERE discr = 'tuteur'";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();

    $query2 = "UPDATE user
              SET user.discr = 'ancien'
              WHERE discr = 'tuteur'";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query2);
    $stmt->execute();

    return true;
}

public function archiveColles() {
    $db = $this->em->getConnection();
    $query = "INSERT INTO banque_colle (id, typeColle, nom, temps_epreuve, matiere_id, dateCreation, ordre, discr) 
              SELECT colle.id, colle.typeColle, colle.nom, colle.temps_epreuve, colle.matiere_id, colle.dateCreation, colle.ordre, colle.discr
              FROM colle";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();

    $query2 = "INSERT INTO banque_colle_qc (id)
               SELECT colle_qc.id
               FROM colle_qc";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query2);
    $stmt->execute();

    return true;
}

public function archiveQC() {
    $db = $this->em->getConnection();
    $query = "INSERT INTO banque_qc (id, titre, id_colle, ordre, qcPere, enonce, donnees, item1, item2, item3, item4,
                          item5, corrige_item1, corrige_item2, corrige_item3, corrige_item4, corrige_item5, item1_vrai,
                          item2_vrai, item3_vrai, item4_vrai, item5_vrai, item1_annule, item2_annule, item3_annule,
                          item4_annule, item5_annule, multiple_choices, inclu) 
              SELECT qc.id, qc.titre, qc.id_colle, qc.ordre, qc.qcPere, qc.enonce, qc.donnees, qc.item1, qc.item2,
                     qc.item3, qc.item4, qc.item5, qc.corrige_item1, qc.corrige_item2, qc.corrige_item3, qc.corrige_item4,
                     qc.corrige_item5, qc.item1_vrai, qc.item2_vrai, qc.item3_vrai, qc.item4_vrai, qc.item5_vrai, 
                     qc.item1_annule, qc.item2_annule, qc.item3_annule, qc.item4_annule, qc.item5_annule, 
                     qc.multiple_choices, qc.inclu
              FROM qc
              ORDER BY qc.qcPere ASC";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();

    return true;
}

public function archivePassages() {
    $db = $this->em->getConnection();
    $query = "INSERT INTO banque_passer_colle (colle_id, dateDebut, note) 
              SELECT passer_colle.colle_id, passer_colle.dateDebut, passer_colle.note
              FROM passer_colle";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();

    return true;
}

public function archiveReponses() {
    $db = $this->em->getConnection();
    $query = "INSERT INTO banque_reponse (id, discr)
              SELECT reponse.id, reponse.discr
              FROM reponse
              WHERE discr='reponseQC'";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();

    $query2 = "INSERT INTO banque_reponse_qc (id, question, A, B, C, D, E, note)
              SELECT reponse_qc.id, reponse_qc.question, reponse_qc.A, reponse_qc.B, reponse_qc.C, reponse_qc.D, 
                     reponse_qc.E, reponse_qc.note
              FROM reponse_qc";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query2);
    $stmt->execute();

    return true;
}

public function archiveStats() {
    $db = $this->em->getConnection();
    $query = "INSERT INTO banque_statistiquecolle (id, colle_id, effectif, moyenne, mediane, note100, major, minor)
              SELECT sc.id, sc.colle_id, sc.effectif, sc.moyenne, sc.mediane, sc.note100, sc.major, sc.minor
              FROM statistiquecolle_groupe scg 
              LEFT JOIN  statistiquecolle sc ON sc.id = scg.statistiquecolle_id
              WHERE scg.groupe_id = 1 
              AND sc.id NOT IN (SELECT sc1.id
                                FROM statistiquecolle_groupe scg1 
                                LEFT JOIN  statistiquecolle sc1 ON sc1.id = scg1.statistiquecolle_id
                                WHERE scg1.groupe_id != 1)";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();

    $query2 = "INSERT INTO banque_statistiquequestion (id, question_id, moyenne, nbReponseTot, nbReponseA, nbReponseB,
                                                       nbReponseC, nbReponseD, nbReponseE)
              SELECT sq.id, sq.question_id, sq.moyenne, sq.nbReponseTot, sq.nbReponseA, sq.nbReponseB, sq.nbReponseC, 
              sq.nbReponseD, sq.nbReponseE
              FROM statistiquequestion_groupe sqg 
              LEFT JOIN  statistiquequestion sq ON sq.id = sqg.statistiquequestion_id
              WHERE sqg.groupe_id = 1 
              AND sq.id NOT IN (SELECT sq1.id
                                FROM statistiquequestion_groupe sqg1 
                                LEFT JOIN  statistiquequestion sq1 ON sq1.id = sqg1.statistiquequestion_id
                                WHERE sqg1.groupe_id != 1)";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query2);
    $stmt->execute();

    $query3 = "INSERT INTO banque_repartitioncolle (id, statColle_id, note, nombre, percentOfEffectif)
              SELECT rc.id, rc.statColle_id, rc.note, rc.nombre, rc.percentOfEffectif
              FROM repartitioncolle rc
              WHERE rc.statColle_id IN (SELECT bsc.id
                                        FROM banque_statistiquecolle bsc)";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query3);
    $stmt->execute();

    $query4 = "INSERT INTO banque_repartitionquestion (id, statQuestion_id, note, nombre, percentOfEffectif)
              SELECT rq.id, rq.statQuestion_id, rq.note, rq.nombre, rq.percentOfEffectif
              FROM repartitionquestion rq
              WHERE rq.statQuestion_id IN (SELECT bsq.id
                                        FROM banque_statistiquequestion bsq)";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query4);
    $stmt->execute();

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into materialized views? http://www.fromdual.com/mysql-materialized-views

Comment: I don't think this will solve it. If I understood well, it's a way to speed up queries.
The main problem here is to transfer some data with inheritance to other tables in a clean way and I can't find how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing a database migration recently, and have found that the easiest method (for me) is to do everything in SQL. It's a bit laborious, but it worked okay for my project

First drop all the constraints

```
# Table1.field1
ALTER TABLE Table1 DROP FOREIGN KEY FK_Table1_field1;
ALTER TABLE Table1 DROP INDEX IDX_Table1_field1;

# Table1.field2
ALTER TABLE Table1 DROP FOREIGN KEY FK_Table1_field2;
ALTER TABLE Table1 DROP INDEX IDX_Table1_field2;
```

Then add all the SQL you have to move the data into the new tables.

Then drop all the old tables

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Table1;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Table2;
```

Then Add all the constraints back in

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 
    ADD INDEX IDX_Table1_field1 (field1 ASC);
ALTER TABLE Table1
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Table1_field1
    FOREIGN KEY (field1)
    REFERENCES OtherTable (xxxx)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

I kept each step in it's own sql file, so for this example there would be 4 sql files, might be easier to manage if you split up the data move step into more than one file as well.